# AWS Lambda returns 502 when using Promise.all()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, serverless

Endpoint is returning 502 in every condition. I think my reponses are correctly structured but I still got 502 Bad Gateway error from my endpoint.

Responses was working when I was not dealing with Promise.all().

Timeout for this function is 30 seconds btw, but it doesn't take that long.

I have a handler like this:

```
module.exports.handler= async function (event, context, callback) {
  await Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()])
    .then((value) => {
      promise3(value[0], value[1])
        .then(() => {
          const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              message: "Successful",
            }),
          };
          callback(null, response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          const response = {
            statusCode: 401,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              message: err,
            }),
          };
          callback(null, response);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: err,
        }),
      };
      callback(null, response);
    });
};
```

The error I am getting from the test from API Gateway:

```
Sat Dec 05 09:24:08 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: null
Sat Dec 05 09:24:08 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy 
response
Sat Dec 05 09:24:08 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stick to using `await` or `.then`, instead of trying to use both.

Since your handler is already `async` you might as well use `await`.

I've modified your code below so that it no longer uses `.then` (not tested).

```
module.exports.handler= async function (event, context, callback) {
    try
    {
        var values = await Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()]);

        try
        {
            await promise3(values[0], values[1]);
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: "Successful",
                })
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 401,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: err,
                })
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
    }
    catch(err) 
    {
        const response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: err,
            })
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot. But in your code you forgot to add "callback(null, response)" in 200 status code case.

Comment: Glad it works. Thanks, I've edited with that callback

Comment: In offline deployement function returns in 2.5 sec but in online it times out(30 sec) do you know why is that happening?

Comment: Ok adding "context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;" fixed issue.